# Regex to return numeric value if it match one string or the other

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a string which can come in two different ways. See the example below:

```
# Option 1
Court Case Fee $214.00

# Option 2
Court Filing Fee: Contract $198.00
```

I want to build a RegEx that will return the first amount without the dollar sign. For example:

- if the string is the Option 1: 214.00
- if the string is the Option 2: 198.00

I have built this RegEx:

```
/Court Case Fee|Court Filing Fee: Contract \$(?<court_case_fee>\d+\.\d+)/mi
```

But is not working since it just returns the value for Option 2. What I am missing here?

Here is the Regex101 so you can play with it: https://regex101.com/r/Od3r6y/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a non capture group `(?:` for both the alternatives, and optionally match `Contract`

Perhaps start the pattern with a word boundary `\b` to prevent a partial word match.

```
\bCourt (?:Case Fee|Filing Fee:) (?:Contract )?\$(?<court_case_fee>\d+\.\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVUcDR/1)

Or the pcre version with a match only, where `\h+` matches 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars and `\K` forgets what is matched so far:

```
\bCourt\h+(?:Case\h+Fee|Filing Fee:)\h+(?:Contract\h+)?\$\K\d+\.\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GxpRCv/1)